# Enforce order of execution in chef recipes

Tags: chef-infra

I have two recipes:

1. Configures my home directory with things like my .bashrc, run on almost every machine I use
2. Mounts an EBS volume containing my home directory. This only gets used by a single EC2 instance at a time, but lets me easily migrate to a new instance

In the case of this EC2 instance when it first boots up, I need recipe #2 to be executed before recipe #1 or the volume won't be mounted yet.  How can I ensure that this order of execution will be explicitly forced?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Chef *always* executes recipes in the order you specify them. It will not arbitrarily reorder things. So if you want one recipe to be run before another, just load them in that order (e.g. In the `run_list`)

To further enforce this (at the expense of additional coupling between your recipes) you can also use `include_recipe` at he beginning of the second recipe to load the first one.

Comment: then what about this http://serverfault.com/questions/604719/chef-recipe-order-of-execution-redux and this http://erik.hollensbe.org/2013/03/16/the-chef-resource-run-queue/ discussion? They both seem to argue there are two distinct compile and run phases, where the compile phase can end up re-ordering things.

Comment: @mmcrae You have indeed two phases: the compile phase where your recipes are evaluated and the resource collection is built and the converge phase where this collection is executed one after another. Normally, resources are just added at the end of the resource collection during the compile phase. You can however influence this (e.g. by custom code or by using notifications). That said, chef will still not randomly re-order resources without an explicit dependency (as e.g. puppet does). It always uses the implicit order the resources are defined in.

Answer (score -4):

If you want these two actions done at login (and not boot time) ...

... and if you need them done in a specific order ...

... then you should simply write a script that invokes *both* of them.  In the correct order.

IMHO...